# Converting transparent pixels to white after mask proccess

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, transparency

I m working on optical mark recognition. My purpose is extracting the red circles from the image and evaluating black shapes after. There is no problem on detecting red circles and extracting them (picture 2), i successfully obtain the image where red pixels are transparent. The problem is that, when i convert this image to grey, transparent pixels becomes black, so nothing changes after all this effort(picture3). How can i convert transparent pixels to white or am I making somethings very wrong?

```
    Mat masked = new Mat(src.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    Mat hsv_image = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, hsv_image, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

    // create mask starts
    Mat lower_red_hue_range = new Mat();
    Mat upper_red_hue_range = new Mat();
    Core.inRange(hsv_image, new Scalar(0, 70, 70), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), lower_red_hue_range);
    Core.inRange(hsv_image, new Scalar(160, 70, 70), new Scalar(179, 255, 255), upper_red_hue_range);
    Mat red_hue_mask = new Mat();
    Core.addWeighted(lower_red_hue_range, 1.0, upper_red_hue_range, 1.0, 0.0, red_hue_mask);
    Core.bitwise_not(red_hue_mask, red_hue_mask);
    Utils.saveAsBitmap(red_hue_mask);  // picture1
    // create mask ends

    // apply mask to src
    src.copyTo(masked, red_hue_mask);
    Utils.saveAsBitmap(masked); // picture2 -> now it has transparent pixels

    // convert to greyscale (transparent pixels become black :( )
    Imgproc.cvtColor(masked, mBlacked, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Utils.saveAsBitmap(mBlacked); // picture3
```

[picture src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skcsc.png)

[picture 1-2-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w2MZ.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "transparent"? I don't see anything related to transparency in that code sample.

Comment: sorry i edited the images. transparent pixels appear after the mask operation(picture2).

Comment: This is odd. Since you use `RGB2HSV` in conversion from `src` to `hsv_image`, I assume that `src` is a 3 channel image (i.e. no alpha transparency channel). Initially `masked` is all white pixels. Then you `copyTo` everything from `src` in places where mask isn't black, the rest is left pure white (which might be what you call "transparent pixels"). | Where does `src` come from? (How do you create that, and acquire the image?) Can you post a sample image (that will match the rest of the attached images), so that we can try to reproduce this?

Comment: i added the src image, i m taking it with a phone camera. it is 4 channel rgba image. besides, masked is initially white, but after the copyTo it has tranparent pixels (i changed picture1-2-3 for clarity, check it again).

Comment: Oh, if `src` is 4 channel, then `src.copyTo(masked, red_hue_mask);` will cause a reallocation of `masked` to be a 4 channel image as well, making the initialization on the 1st line of your sample irrelevant. That would somewhat explain the rest, although I would have expected the conversions from RGB to complain if they were given an RGBA as source -- I guess they just ignore the alpha channel. In your place, I'd just drop the alpha channel from the source image, I don't see any reason for it in what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: exactly! i made rgba -> rgb conversion for the src and problem resolved. many thanks. i accept as an answer if you write.